# Angular Material - radio button label font-size too big

Tags: css, angular-material

As you can see by this image, the font size for the `mat-radio` label is way off the font size for everything else.

[image]

This is the relevant template part:

```
<mat-radio-group formControlName="choice">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <mat-radio-button value="1">Ogni secondo</mat-radio-button>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <mat-radio-button value="2">Ogni</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-form-field>
           <mat-select formControlName="every">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let i of seconds" [value]="i + 1">
                 {{ i + 1 }}
              </mat-option>
           </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        secondo/i partendo dal secondo
    ...
```

I've tried via custom typography, using their SASS mixins and functions, described in the typography doc section. Already tried that means I tried injecting a custom typography in the `mat-core` import, as per https://material.angular.io/guide/typography

Any idea?

Edit: setting a custom font-size for the class `.mat-radio-label-content` produces this result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the font size in the material's css itself. You can't override it with css written in your own css file.

Comment: By "change" I think you mean using their SASS mixins and functions, described in the typography doc section. Already tried that, which means I tried injecting a custom typography in the mat-core import, as per https://material.angular.io/guide/typography

Comment: no, find the core css file of material in your project. In that you can override the css by writing your new style at the bottom or directly changing the default value by searching the selector.

Comment: Hi, Please try this for once. add a style tag at the bottom in your body tag, in your main "index.html" file and take the selector you want to change (eg: .mat-radio-button), and add style. see if it works

Comment: If this works, add a stylesheet manually in your index.html and override the styles of material in that file.

Answer (score 2):

```
::ng-deep .mat-radio-outer-circle {
    height: 15px !important;
    width: 15px !important;
    top: 3px !important;
    border-width: 1px !important;
}
::ng-deep .mat-radio-inner-circle{
    height: 15px !important;
    width: 15px !important;
    top: 3px !important;
}
```

You can set height, width and top for both outer and inner circles om radio button. This works for me

Answer (score 0):

There must a default theme you have included for Angular Material and hence it is picking up the default height for the radio label.

"mat-radio-label-content" => This is the class name of the element which you can target to set font size.

If it does not allow as natively then use :ng-deep.

Comment: I tried that, the result is not great. Seems the font-size is being inherited by the global scope. See updated question

Comment: I have tried this but does not work. I had to override by writing the style in the material's core css.